# MySQL replacing column with another one when null

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

I'm trying to retrieve data from two joined tables in MySQL.

````
   table1                   table2
   id                         id - foreign key
   name                    address_old
```other col```            address_new
````

I would like to get 'name' and 'address_new', or 'name' and 'address_old' if 'address_new' is null.

I've already tried

```
ifnull(table2.address_new, tables2.address_old)
CASE WHEN table2.address_new IS NULL 
    THEN table2.address_old 
    ELSE table2.address_new
coalesce(table2.address_new, table2.address_old)
```

Neither one is working and I keep getting empty results for these.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the table schemas and the full query you are trying?

Comment: Maybe your `address_new` is not null, but an empty string? Try something like `IFNULL(NULLIF(address_new, ''), address_old)`

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto turned out it was an empty string. This works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @BartFriederichs fixed it. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need check both  null and empty string

```
select t1.name, CASE WHEN table2.address_new IS NULL or  table2.address_new =''
    THEN table2.address_old 
    ELSE table2.address_new address
END as 'Address'
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just check for the presence of data.  Something like:

```
(CASE WHEN table2.address_new > '' THEN table2.address_new
      ELSE table2.address_old 
 END)
```

Or, if white space and other non-alphanumeric characters are an issue, you can look for a valid character:

```
(CASE WHEN table2.address_new REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9]' THEN table2.address_new
      ELSE table2.address_old 
 END)
```